# gdb error while executing compile command: libcc1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: gcc, gdb, shared-libraries, gcc6

I compiled the most recent gdb version from source to try out the new `compile` command. But unfortunately, it gives the error `Could not load libcc1.so: libcc1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` whenever I try to execute `compile` command. I checked if I have the library `libcc1.so` installed and I have. In fact looking at the installed libraries in [here](http://clfs.org/view/sysvinit/sparc64/final-system/gcc.html), it looks like gcc already installs libcc1.so. My gcc version is 6.1 btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying the file libcc1.so.0.0.0 as libcc1.so in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ did the trick

Comment: From *where* did you copied this?

Comment: It was the same directory as I remember. Sorry for the delay btw